# Xcode 11 can't reallocate Info.plist into a group

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

I just updated to Xcode 11. But when I move Info.plist to a new group, Xcode can't locate it and I can't tell Xcode where is it on Identity

Comment: I have posted an answer , I think it works. @Csb

Answer (score 10):

**Go to Build settings then find Packaging section**

Then find Info.plist File in Packaging section and change correct path.

For Example

If you create a Test Group into Test Project then default path is `Test/Info.plist` showing in Packaging section , Change this path to `Test/TestGroup/Info.plist`.

**Project_Name/Group_Name/Info.plist**

[image]